# Reading huge file and processing it

Tags: python, file

I have few list of dictionaries as follows in a file

```
[1,{'a':1,'b':8,'c':15}]
[2,{'j':2,'k':10,'a':15}]
........................
........................
```

and I have a master dictionary which contain all the keys of the above list of dictionary in the following format
{0:'c', 1:'b', 2:'j', 3:'a', 4:'k'}

for each of the line i want to process the dictionary as follow
[1,{3:1,1:8,0:15}]
[2,{2:2,4:10,3:15}]

here the value is same as the value of the input line.and the key will be key corresponding to that value in the master dictionary.

```
for list1elem in listofemail[1:]:
            d = {k: list1elem[v] for k,v in vocab_dic.items() if v in list1elem}
            print(d)
```

But it took lot of time as my file contain around 25000 of lines and master dictionary contain 25000 of word.I have also reading files like this from 8 directories.so I have two more for loop

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('email'):
   files = [fi for fi in files if not fi.startswith("kjjii")]
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
         with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
          lines = f.read().splitlines()
         for list1elem in listofemail[1:]:
            d = {k: list1elem[v] for k,v in vocab_dic.items() if v in list1elem}
            print(d)
```

It is running for 15 mins.Need help to optimize it.

Comment: You won't get any help on such confusing post , Please try to be specific , what you are trying to achieve , by posting a sample example instead of big picuture in you mind, what you have tried so far, then as last you can post the Big picture problem , Else it's so difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest I can think of, without using multiprocessing. If you were on python3, you could optimize all the `d[k]` calls with a call to `d.items()` (or `d.iteritems()` in python2).

```
import os
import ast

master = {0:'c', 1:'b', 2:'j', 3:'a', 4:'k'}
masterev = {master[k]:k for k in master}

answer = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk('email'):
    for fname in fnames:
        if not fname.startswith('kijiji'): continue
        if not fname.endswith('.txt'): continue

        contents = []
        fpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        with open(fpath) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                L = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
                for num, d in L:
                    contents.append([num, {masterev[k]:d[k] for k in d}])

        answer[fpath] = contents
```